# TFD TDD relevance in larger products

Tags: process, tdd, sdlc

I was wondering about the feasibility and the realistic gains we achieve by following the Test First Design approach in larger products.

Although I am a strong believer in deciding the scope before jumping into coding, for a larger product, I"m really not sure if the **TDD** holds.

Realistic Problems with a larger product:
1. The size of the product makes it much harder to maintain all the test cases.
2. The unit boundaries, slowly become less defined and sometimes unwanted coupling results between different units.
3. Testing a unit might not suffice the functionality of the developed structure as such (A possible result of tight coupling)
4. The initial thought process and the vision might get diluted with the product size. This in turn dilutes the definition of the units and test cases become mere process requirements rather than serving the purpose of being the **guardians** of a piece of code.

My view no this situation of product growth is to stop the growth of the product and remove the unwanted bits. Start to clean up the product to have only those features which define the product. The other features, either already developed or being developed can be given as addons. And these **core** set of features of the product need to be ***guarded*** using a strong set of Unit Test Cases which define the **Unit's** functionality alone.

Any more suggestions? I would love to hear from you guys as I currently am facing this situation of coupling of units and the redundant test cases which actually don't do much. And all of this is introduced due to the size of the product growing almost each and every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TDD will work for any size project. Personally I work on a system with at my last count, around 650,000 lines of C Sharp. We could have never approached such a size without a suite of tests backing our changes up and preventing regressions.
2. Remember the difference between Test First and Test Driven (TDD). If you follow test driven development and let the tests drive the code you create, coupling should not be a problem. The same cannot be said for TFD, it would be up the developers to control this level of quality.
3. See point one. In fact, unit tests would be the best bet for advance functionality anywhere. Check this [article about how many tests you need per path](http://www.jbrains.ca/permalink/integrated-tests-are-a-scam-part-1) in your code. You could use integration tests but as the article points out, the number you would need would be more than the number of unit tests you need.
4. This is up to the team. Test code should be treated as a first class citizen. This is especially true if the project is going to be as "large" as you reckon, the slightest regression could be costly.

With regards your last question, my recommendation would be to ensure you core domain logic is as tested and stable as possible. It will be up to you and your team to find out what is the "core" of your application. The remaining infrastructure can be fairly loose, but there should be little to no logic in this layer anyway. Lock down the domain, and the rest should follow suit.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But my specific problem is with the dilution of vision of the core product. You start with a core set of functionalities. These are well developed using TDD, slowly, you enhance your core. After after a long time you realize that the core in itself is quite large. And the maintenance of the test cases becomes a bigger headache. I too am currently working on a project with around 700,000 lines of code and this is the precise problem  I'm facing.

Comment: @Unsung - what is the problem with the maintenance of the test cases? Fragile tests? Slow tests? Etc... If the core is really so unmanageable you might want to break it down as you previously mentioned, though it depends on the symptoms of why the tests are hard to manage. Typically we have a Core project, along with a thin web app/service layer. The only time we find the tests hard to manage is when they are poorly developed, testing too much and so on.

Comment: The problem is the sheer number and purpose of the test cases. Running the test cases takes a lot of time. Also, a developer might move out of the current project to another one. Any change done to the core engine might require a change of the test cases(Which is perfectly acceptable) but the efforts spent just to fix the test cases might actually slow down the process. This is where I believe that as someone managing a project, the size of the core engine should be a driving factor.

Comment: Potentially. I see tests breaking as a "good thing", especially if we are adding new functionality. For example if we have a function that returns 1, suddenly we start returning -1. Tests should break. At this point you'd double check requirements, have conversations with the business about what requirement is correct. If you simply disregard a failure you might be breaking something that actually matters. We practice SOA, of those 650k lines of code, there are numerous projects that split the codebase up into manageable, reusable chunks. Having one "big" project will naturally cause issues.

Comment: @Unsung, the separation of the projects minimizes the time it takes for a change to go through. Also you tend to find developers naturally know more about one part of the codebase, rather than the other. Tests breaking either mean the test quality needs to improve, or the requirements are conflicting. This might feel slow, but at least you get instant feedback when you do break something, rather than debugging a problem you created six months ago ;)

Comment: For now, I don't see a solution to the problem. But I agree with you regarding finding issues earlier than later due to failing test cases. The only hope is that the developer has written a meaningful test case and not some test case for the heck of it!